# can't run a django project with apache on a subdomain

Tags: django, apache, dns, subdomain

I have an online shop which contains a main page and a shop page. now this main page and shop page are actually two different projects, so in order to have them online, I have to run two instances of django.

now the things is, i want to have the main page on www.setakshop.ir, and the shop on shop.setakshop.ir. The thing is, after setting up the necessary settings, both shop.setakshop.ir and setakshop.ir point to the main page! and I can only see the shop page through setakshop.ir:8000, which I expected apache to proxy it to shop.setakshop.ir
I serve the DNS myself and here are my DNS settings:

```
;
; BIND data file for setakshop.ir
;
$TTL    3h
@       IN      SOA     ns1.setakshop.ir. admin.setakshop.ir. (
                          1        ; Serial
                          3h       ; Refresh after 3 hours
                          1h       ; Retry after 1 hour
                          1w       ; Expire after 1 week
                          1h )     ; Negative caching TTL of 1 day
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.setakshop.ir.
@       IN      NS      ns2.setakshop.ir.


setakshop.ir.    IN      MX      10      mail.setakshop.ir.
setakshop.ir.    IN      A       xx.xx.xx.xx
ns1                     IN      A       xx.xx.xx.xx
ns2                     IN      A       xx.xx.xx.xx
www                     IN      CNAME   setakshop.ir.
mail                    IN      A       xx.xx.xx.xx
ftp                     IN      CNAME   setakshop.ir.
shop                     IN     A     xx.xx.xx.xx
```

and when run

```
nslookup shop.setakshop.ir
```

i get a valid response. So I think the DNS setup is actually fine.

Now the other thing I suspect, is my apache settings. I suspect that I haven't set the proxy settings right. here it is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIDaemonProcess main python-path=/var/www/setak:/var/www/setak/setakenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup main
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/setak/setakenv/main/ashop/ashop/ashop/wsgi.py
    ServerAdmin admin@setakshop.ir
    ServerName www.setakshop.ir
    ProxyPass / http://www.setakshop.ir:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://www.setakshop.ir:8001/

    Alias /media/ /var/www/setak/setakenv/main/ashop/ashop/static/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/setak/setakenv/main/ashop/ashop/static/

    <Directory /var/www/setak/setakenv/main/ashop/ashop/static>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/setak/setakenv/main/ashop/ashop/static/media>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>    

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:8080>
    WSGIDaemonProcess setak python-path=/var/www/setak:/var/www/setak/setakenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup setak
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/wsgi.py
    ServerAdmin admin@setakshop.ir
    ServerName shop.setakshop.ir

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://shop.setakshop.ir:8000
    ProxyPassReverse / http://shop.setakshop.ir:8000

    Alias /robots.txt /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/static/robots.txt

    Alias /media/ /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/media/
    Alias /static/ /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/static/

    <Directory /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/static>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/setak/setakenv/setakmain/django-oscar/sites/sandbox/public/media>
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>    

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Now I dont get what I'm doing wrong here!
I run both the projects with the following command :

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8001
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't even know where to start form. First, the django server is not appropriate for production: "runserver is intended only for development on your local machine, not for exposure on the public Web.". https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/

Comment: well I did the deployment according to this tutorial
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-django-with-mod_wsgi-and-apache-with-a-virtualenv-python-environment-on-a-debian-vps
 so the its on them! My hypothesis was that the wsgi script will handle the deployment, alongside mod_wsgi

Comment: No, that tutorial doesn't even mention using Apache as a proxy. And the only time it mentions runserver is to test that Django is set up correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That *really* is not how you run Django applications via Apache. `runserver` is not designed for or appropriate for production; it makes no sense to use Apache as a reverse proxy to runserver.

Confusingly it seems that you have correctly set up `WSGIScriptAlias` for one of your sites, but you are still proxying it. You need to remove the proxy stuff altogether, forget about runserver, and use mod_wsgi throughout.

The way to get Apache to serve two sites on two domains is to use NamedVirtualHosts. You simply set up two separate ones, each with the correct server name.

Comment: thank you very much. the problem with your answer is that it too general, and I am so new to this, so would you mind adding details to your solution?

Comment: This answer is pretty specific...It outlines exactly what you need to do to fix things. Apart from completely writing your Apache config, this answer has it all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not use ./manage.py runserver along with apache and you should not use ./manage.py runserver when you move your website to production. runserver is only for development environment, it can handle only one request at a time.

You should use mod_wsgi for running your project using Apache. Look the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/)

Or else [gunicorn](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/run.html) and nginx can be used for running your project. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368897/cant-run-a-django-project-with-apache-on-a-subdomain).